# Multiprocessing with python application to shave running time that is currently 36 hours

Tags: python, multiprocess

I am currently working on a data mining project that is creating a similarity matrix that is 18000x18000

Here are the two methods which build the matrix

```
def CreateSimilarityMatrix(dbSubsetData, distancePairsList):

    global matrix
    matrix = [ [0.0 for y in range(dbSubsetData.shape[0])] for x in range(dbSubsetData.shape[0])]
    for i in range(len(dbSubsetData)): #record1

        SimilarityArray = []
        start = time.time()
        for j in range(i+1, len(dbSubsetData)): #record2
            Similarity = GetDistanceBetweenTwoRecords(dbSubsetData, i, j, distancePairsList)

            #The similarities are all very small numbers which might be why the preference value needs to be so precise. 
            #Let's multiply the value by a scalar 10 to give the values more range. 
            matrix[i][j] = Similarity * 10.0
            matrix[j][i] = Similarity * 10.0

        end = time.time()
    return matrix

def GetDistanceBetweenTwoRecords(dbSubsetData, i, j, distancePairsList):

    Record1 = dbSubsetData.iloc[i]
    Record2 = dbSubsetData.iloc[j]
    columns = dbSubsetData.columns
    distancer    = 0.0
    distancec    = 0.0

    for i in range(len(Record1)):

        columnName = columns[i]
        Record1Value = Record1[i]
        Record2Value = Record2[i]

        if(Record1Value != Record2Value):
            ob = distancePairsList[distancePairsDict[columnName]-1]

            if(ob.attributeType == "String"):
                strValue = Record1Value+":"+Record2Value
                strValue2 = Record2Value+":"+Record1Value

                if strValue in ob.distancePairs:
                    val = ((ob.distancePairs[strValue])**2) 
                    val = val * -1
                    distancec = distancec + val
                elif strValue2 in ob.distancePairs:
                    val = ((ob.distancePairs[strValue2])**2)
                    val = val * -1
                    distancec = distancec + val

            elif(ob.attributeType == "Number"):
                val = ((Record1Value - Record2Value)*ob.getSignificance())**2 
                val = val * -1
                distancer = distancer + val

    distance = distancer + distancec
    return distance
```

Each iteration is looping 18000x19 times (18000 for each row and 19 times for each attribute). The total number of iterations is (18000x18000x19)/2 since it is symmetric and therefore I only have to do one half of the matrix. This will take around 36 hours to complete, which is a timeframe I obviously want to shave down.

I figured Multiprocessing is the trick. Since each row is independently generating numbers and fitting them to the matrix, I could run multiprocess with CreateSimilarityMatrix. So I created this in the function which will create my processes

```
matrix = [ [0.0 for y in range(SubsetDBNormalizedAttributes.shape[0])] for x in range(SubsetDBNormalizedAttributes.shape[0])] 
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    procs = []
    for i in range(4):
        proc = Process(target=CreateSimilarityMatrix, args=(SubsetDBNormalizedAttributes, distancePairsList, i, 4))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
```

CreateSimilarityMatrix is now changed to

```
def CreateSimilarityMatrix(dbSubsetData, distancePairsList, counter=0, iteration=1):

    global Matrix

    for i in range(counter, len(dbSubsetData), iteration): #record1

        SimilarityArray = []
        start = time.time()
        for j in range(i+1, len(dbSubsetData)): #record2
            Similarity = GetDistanceBetweenTwoRecords(dbSubsetData, i, j, distancePairsList)
            #print("Similarity Between Records",i,":",j," is ", Similarity)

            #The similarities are all very small numbers which might be why the preference value needs to be so precise. 
            #Let's multiply the value by a scalar 10 to give the values more range. 
            Matrix[i][j] = Similarity * 10.0
            Matrix[j][i] = Similarity * 10.0

        end = time.time()
        print("Iteration",i,"took",end-start,"(s)")
```

Currently this goes s-l-o-w. It's really slow. It takes minutes to start one process, then it takes minutes to start the next one. I thought these were supposed to run concurrently? Is my application of the process incorrect?

Comment: What's `GetDistanceBetweenTwoRecords`? Rewriting that to work with entire NumPy arrays at once using standard NumPy optimization techniques is likely to get a lot more bang for your buck than parallel processing. You're losing way more time than you think to Python overhead.

Comment: Have you tried to use NumPy, because Python for work with Matrix is reeeealy slow. You should read this (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), and give it a go.

Comment: @FernandoMarques: Not `numpy.matrix`. Take that big "It is no longer recommended to use this class" warning seriously. Regular NumPy arrays are the way to go.

Comment: Actually let me ask a clarification question. The variable Matrix is a regular python array, but dbSubsetData is a pandas array. Are you talking about the Matrix array itself? Use numpy for matrix?

Comment: GetDistanceBetweenTwoRecords takes the dbSubsetData,  i, and j, and an object distancePairsList. I get the records i, and j from dbSubsetData. What I do is go through each column and get the distance between [rowi][column] and [rowj][column]. The distance value is located in my distance value pairs which is an array of objects. Each object contains the pair distances for each potential column value. So one object per attribute with multiple possible distance pairs. If there is a way to do the whole thing for all columns in the same row in one shot that would definitely speed things up.

Comment: I was able to shave off 7 seconds by simply taking any pandas arrays and transforming them into numpy arrays through the property "value". This is beginning to have me check to see if I use pandas anywhere else in my loops. Numpy is definitely the way to go here.Each row instead of taking 15 to 16 seconds now take 7 to 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CPython, there is something called the global interpreter lock (GIL) that makes it difficult to actually multithread while making things faster, and can instead slow it down substantially.

If you are dealing with matrices, use numpy, which is definitely a lot faster than regular Python.

Comment: This is correct. GIL makes multithreading pointless for CPU intensive threads, and OP should use multiprocessing.

Comment: I actually am using multiprocessing. I mistakingly said I used multithreading. The library and routine i am using is a multiprocessing approach from this page. https://www.journaldev.com/15631/python-multiprocessing-example. I have edited the page to make that clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, should I delete my answer? (I’m somewhat new to the site)

Comment: I'm actually using yours and others direction concerning numpy, so that part of the answer is certainly still valid.

Comment: This was the solution! That is, nevermind about multiprocessing. If you are going to be building and reading from a database that has 10,000s of records, USE Numpy! Do NOT use Pandas or python arrays. Thanks for the tip. Now each iteration is taking less than a second. What took 36 hours will now take around 90 minutes. It's that drastic.